# Windows Services on a Laptop work station

Tags: windows, service

OK, I have worked on hardware on computers since 8086 days. I got in to teaching electronics where I work to Forklift Techs. But recently where has dumped out IT person and gave it to me to do. I know little to nothing about Domains and the settings that go with them, but I am learning as I go. So please be gentle....

I have about 190 computers in 10 branches, in 5 states I keep up with. Most of it is simple things. So I use a program called "Instant House Call" to work on them remotley. It is a very good program and will even allow me to reboot a machine and still maintain control. It also has a remote access where I can log on anytime the machine is running if I have them download it with "Remote Access Allowed" button checked.

I have come across this one computer that does not have that choice, and will not allow me to reboot and maintain control. The Tech support tells me that the computer has to be able to run "Windows Services"  but offered no more help.

What do I need to do?

Thanks

Comment: What OS is the computer running?

Comment: ahm, the question is about "Windows" services...:)

Comment: @Traveling Tech Guy:  I think David was trying to politely suggest that maybe the computer *isn't* running Windows, and that in fact is the problem.

Comment: Either isn't running windows, or client is not installed, failing that something is blocking ports...

Comment: This should go to superuser.

Comment: For the record, I voted for migration to SuperUser. :P

Comment: The context of this question makes it appropriate for SF, not SU.

Answer (score 1):

This definitely means that the program you use installs some 'service', type of a program that executes upon start-up but is not showing up in the task manager.

Start -> Settings -> Control Panel

*then*

Administrative Tools -> Computer Management

*then*

Services and Applications -> Services

There you will find all the services which are running/stopped and enable/disable them. If the service from the program you are installing is not working, you may check Event Viewer in the same 'Computer Management' toolie.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I'll check it out tomorrow. It is runnung XP pro, and in a new full install after a hard drive falure. I installed it on the domain, and gave the user "Power User" previgles.

Comment: Next time please post comments like this in your own question.